# How to get the new PayPal Express Checkout UI

Tags: user-interface, paypal, express-checkout

When using the express checkout API and redirecting the user to PayPal I'm getting the older UI. **How do I get the new UI instead?**

Here's the SDK I'm using

[PayPal Merchant SDK for .NET](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-dotnet)

Let's take Netflix for example. The URL is the same for both of these examples, however the Netflix checkout is showing the new UI and mine isn't. The only difference in the URLs is the token. What could I be missing to get the new Checkout UI? I haven't found anything in the API docs about it yet.

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token={myToken}

[image]

And how my checkout page looks:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new checkout flow has not been ramped up to 100% at this point in time. whenever an instance of express checkout is initiated you could be prompted with either checkout flow. This is something that is handled on the PayPal side an not anything that you would have to change or modify.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks for the response Brandon.